# Type mismatch with type parameters

Tags: scala

I have following trait:

```
sealed trait Tree[+A]
case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
case class Branch[A](left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
```

Then I define a variable with type `Branch`:

```
val t = Branch(Branch(Leaf("S"), Leaf(2)), Leaf(99))
```

The code above works fine. But when I change it to:

```
val t = Branch[Int](Branch(Leaf("S"), Leaf(2)), Leaf(99))
```

The compiler complains:

```
Error:(41, 37) type mismatch;
 found   : String("S")
 required: Int
    val t = Branch[Int](Branch(Leaf("S"), Leaf(2)), Leaf(99))
```

When I determine the type on the first `Branch`(In this case is Int) then the nodes will inherent from parent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens here is that in the case of `Branch(Leaf("S"), Leaf(2))` the compiler will try to find a common type. In the case of `Int` and `String`, their supertype will be `Any`.

The problem is you are forcing the type in the branch definition using `Branch[Int]` which is invalidated by the contained `Branch[Any]`. Removing the `[Int]` will fix the compile error but you'll end up having as a result a `Branch[Any]`.

Let's breakdown a bit your definition:

```scala
sealed trait Tree[+A]
```

The `+` here says that type `A` can be covariant. I won't get into details about variance as there are lots of good articles explaining it (e.g. [here](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html#variance)). Basically it means that a if `String` is a subtype of `Any` then a `Tree[String]` will be a subtype of `Tree[Any]`.

```scala
case class Branch[A](left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
```

Let's first notice how `A` appears both in the left tree and in the right tree. So what happens when we take two trees that have different types and put them in the same branch?

```scala
val left  = Leaf(1)   // Tree[Int]
val right = Leaf("a") // Tree[String]
val tree  = Branch(left, right) // Tree[???]
```

Since `A` has to be the same in the `left` and `right` values (that's how we defined it), the compiler tries to solve this. So it asks itself: what is the first common type of `Int` and `String`?

```
       Any
        ^
       / \
      /   \
     /     \
AnyVal     AnyRef
   /         \
  Int       String
   \         /
       ...
```

This is the type hierarchy in Scala quite simplified. It's better illustrated [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/unified-types.html). Thus, the common supertype of `String` and `Int` is `Any` and that's why the your tree will be a `Tree[Any]`.

Comment: So the type `Any` will be use anywhere, when I do not force a proper type?

Comment: Nope, the first common type will be used. In this case it's `Any`.

Comment: When I force the type to be an `Int`, then all the type of nodes and leaf will be `Int`? It will inherent from branch?

Comment: Yes, so basically everything inside that tree (branch) will have to be either `Int` or one of its subtypes. I'll edit the answer to give you a better overview.

Comment: What to do mean with subtypes? Subtypes of `Int`?

Comment: Yes - in this case it's `Nothing`. Please review the edited answer and also if you're curious about `Nothing` which you might be don't forget to check the last link :) I hope this helps you